# How to create an Enhanced Transaction Security Policy with more than one comparand value for a field

Tags: event-monitoring, transaction-security-policy

**Use Case**

- Block report exports of more than 3 rows from either the Contact or Order object

**I tried this:**

[image]

> Note the typical multi-valued filter as one would see in Reports or ListViews

RESULT: No blockage occurs.

> Why would this be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as of V47, you can't have multi-valued comparands like `Order,Contact`. Instead, you need to do this with uni-valued comparands and use custom condition logic of the form `... AND ( 3 OR 4 ) ...`. The picture illustrates this

[image]